# Trim characters from RSS feed

Tags: php, html, trim

I'm calling in a RSS feed to my website using PHP. Currently my code below is calling in the entire contents for pubDate:

```
<pubDate>Thu, 12 Sep 2013 07:23:59 +0000</pubDate>
```

How do I just display the day and month from the above example i.e. 12 Sep?

**EDIT**

I should clarify, the above line of code is an example output I currently get but as I'm calling the latest 3 posts from an RSS feed, this date and time will vary. I therefore need the code to be more dynamic (if that's the right term!)

This code is my full code that fetches the contents of an RSS feed:

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://tutorial.world.edu/feed/");
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    $title = (string) $item->title; // Title Post
    $link   = (string) $item->link; // Url Link
    $pubDate   = (string) $item->pubDate; // date
    $description = (string) $item->description; //Description Post

    echo '<div class="display-rss-feed"><a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank" title="" >'.$title.' </a><br/><br/>';
    echo $description.'<hr><p style="background-color:#e4f;">'.$pubDate.'</p></div>';

    if($counter == 2 ) {
        break;
    } else {
        $counter++;
    }

} ?>
```

Comment: Try strtotime with date functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/strtotime) and [`date`](http://www.php.net/date):

```
$pubDate = 'Thu, 12 Sep 2013 07:23:59 +0000';

$pubDate = date('j M', strtotime($pubDate)); //This is the only one you need!

var_dump($pubDate); //string(6) "12 Sep"
```

Comment: I should clarify, the variable you've used is an example output I currently have but it could change as I'm calling the latest 3 posts from an RSS feed. Therefore date and times may change.

Comment: @egr103 I know. The first line is only so you actually get an output in my example. **The only line you need in your code is the second one - the rest is examples**. `strtotime` is very good at understanding most dates, so pretty much no matter what you feed it, it'll be able to turn it into a unix timestamp for use in `date`.

Comment: Ah right. Thats my lack of understanding for you! Thats worked so thanks for your explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the date using [date_parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) and then use the values of `month` and `day` in the resulting array.

Comment: Question has been updated to clarify things a bit more. After doing some reading combined with my novice knowledge, it doesn't look as if I can use date_parse?

Answer (score 0):

Even this works

```
<?php
$str="<pubDate>Thu, 12 Sep 2013 07:23:59 +0000</pubDate>";
$str=explode(" ",$str);
echo $str[1]." ".$str[2];//12 Sep
```

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://tutorial.world.edu/feed/");
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    $title = (string) $item->title; // Title Post
    $link   = (string) $item->link; // Url Link
    $pubDate   = (string) $item->pubDate; // date
    $pubDate=explode(" ",$pubDate);
    $pubDate =  $pubDate[1]." ".$pubDate[2];
    $description = (string) $item->description; //Description Post

    echo '<div class="display-rss-feed"><a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank" title="" >'.$title.' </a><br/><br/>';
    echo $description.'<hr><p style="background-color:#e4f;">'.$pubDate.'</p></div>';

    if($counter == 2 ) {
        break;
    } else {
        $counter++;
    }

} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use preg_match() function with desired regular express to fetch particular data.
for example

$content="Thu, 12 Sep 2013 07:23:59 +0000";

preg_match("/.*,(. *)20[0-9][0-9]/"," $content",$g_val) ;

$g_val[1] would have " 12 Sep"